# Plotting each pixel values in raster time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have made a stack and time series for MODIS derived NDVI tiff image. I have a raster time series (eg. 10 years) with the raster dimensions as : 551, 674, 371374, 365  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers). Now, I want to learn and execute 
1. Plot a time series graph for each pixel
2. Plot a time series graph one by one for each pixel and save them in a different file so that I could identify pixel showing abnormal behavior.

Since I am new to R, a detailed steps and help would be much appreciated.

Best, 
Kris

Answer (score 1):

I was going to put this in a comment, but I got a bit carried away and hit the character limit. This is more advice rather than the answer you're looking for:

I didn't downvote, but the last time I asked a question of how to do X without showing an attempt first I was downvotted (a lot). I would suggest you make an attempt first and ask questions on specific things as you need them.

Functions/steps you may need:

1. `load` or `read.csv` to get your data (google/search SO for import data into R)
2. Install packages you need, e.g. `install.packages("ggplot2")`. Typically when you see answers on SO for R they will state what packages are needed.
3. Maybe `library(dplyr)` to make any data manipulations or similar after you've read in your  data. If you need to make lots of data calculations I suggest you become very friendly with dataframes.
4. `library(ggplot)` to plot your images. There are other packages out there and this is my personal preference.
5. I would suggest a basic `plot <- ggplot(...)` and successively add layers (e.g. for loop) by `+ geom_point(...)` and save each new layer addition using `ggsave(...)`

Best of luck with it!

Comment: Thanks @Alwin. I have another issue with the following code-           
files <- list.files("..................", pattern = "MOD13A1*")
stack1 <- stack(files) 
stack1
values<-extract(stack1,1:ncell(stack1))
coord<-xyFromCell(stack1,1:ncell(stack1))
combine<-cbind(coord,values)
write.table(combine,"xyvalues.txt") 

When I run line 4, I get NA, but there are values in each cells of the raster. Any suggestions what is wrong or how can I extract values?